# I am getting :server IP address could not be found (DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN) on new Wordpress site

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to host a WordPress website on Google Cloud Platform. I purchased the domain from Google Domains.

I was getting an `Error: Token mismatch` error on www.whatsmydns.net. The error has gone, but the website is still inaccessible with the domain name.

I still get this error message in in Google Chrome:

```
server IP address could not be found (DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN)
```

I believe the DNS settings have been done correctly, the setup was done around 12 hours ago. Kindly suggest me whether I should wait further, before lodging a complain to Google Domains.

Additional Details:

1. The website is accessible only through the IP address.
2. Unable to change the domain name in wordpress General settings.

Thanks.

Comment: It can occasionally take some time for DNS records to be updated (assuming you have set up DNS correctly at this point). You may wish to edit the question to share some details about that setup if the problem doesn't resolve itself shortly.

Comment: If the problem does not disappear by itself, complain to Google Domains.

Comment: 24 hours or longer is the generally recommended wait time, but is usually shorter in practice. I would personally contact Google after that time frame.

Comment: @Anaksunaman thank you very much, I shall do so.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. When asking your question about that, the domain is also included in here so the answerer can check it too.

DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN is typically due to a misconfiguration or problem with your DNS.

**You should immediately contact via chat or call the relevant party for quick assistance:**
I recommend from chat. Usually it is quickly responded to and can even speak kindly
https://domains.google.com/contactus
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Appreciate your guidance,

The Issue has been resolved,

I had not created the A, Cname record in Google Domains,

The moment i created it the website was functioning fine.

I would like to apologize for my earlier response,in which i mentioned that DNS setup was done correctly.

Was a huge learning curve.